# What control from InfoPath 2007 maps as SPFieldLookUp or SPFieldLookUpCollection field?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath, spfield

Does anyone know what control from InfoPath 2007 maps as SPFieldLookUp or SPFieldLookUpCollection field in SharePoint?

Any idea is accepted.

Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

till now i did not manage to find such control. i assume that there is no such control in infopath :(